# And the witnesses laid their coats at the feet of a young man named Saul?

Tags: jesus, luke, acts, hebrews, saul

Act 7:58
**Why is this mention in the bible? Is it because of the following**

Luke wanted to introduce Saul here, in some filmy-like plot (not just plainly - he was to be a special figure in the Bible, in the latter part of it).  He was knowing who Saul was but wanted his introduction to be quick and curious. Since in Act 8:1 - it is said **Saul approved the killing of Stephen** - it basically says, Saul was in charge of this group and was the leader - so he was the only one who was giving the order and supervising the killing of Stephen, so, the only choice left for the killer to hand over their jackets (may they take off the clothes to get it stained from the blood of Stephen)

Is my understanding right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this question clearly.  Obviously, Paul must enter the narrative at some point.  So, what are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Acts 7:58 is definitely a sign of a new beginning as witnesses laid their coats at the feet of a young man named Saul.

It  was the introduction of Saul as the one who had  the authority to supervise the killing of Stephen, a man
full grace and power who was performing great wonders and signs among the people.
False witness accused him of blasphemy, a deadly charge. Just as evil men had accused Jesus of blasphemy.

> And as they were stoning Stephen, ..he cried in a loud voice, “Lord, do not place this sin to them.” Acts 7:60

One must wonder if Saul heard these words similar to what Christ so graciously spoke when he was on the cross dying  asking
God the Father to forgive them.

Saul was then empowered and emboldened to destroy the believers, and caused them to scatter out of Jerusalem

> Saul was destroying the church. Entering houses after houses and dragging off men and women, he was delivering them to prison.  Acts 8:3

> 1Saul was still breathing out murderous threats against the disciples of the Lord. He approached the high priest 2and requested letters to the synagogues in Damascus, so that if he found any men or women belonging to the Way, he could bring them as prisoners to Jerusalem.  acts 9:1-2

Suddenly something happened to Saul in the midst of his rage, hatred, jealousy and destruction of believers lives.

> Saul drew near to Damascus on his journey, suddenly a light from heaven flashed around him. 4He fell to the ground and heard a voice say to him, “Saul, Saul, why do you persecute Me?   Acts 9:3

The glorified Jesus Christ blinded Paul, spoke to him and instantly opened up his eyes to who he was.  Lord

Saul was the beginning of something brand new, A vessel for the grace of God would be clearly seen in a man who was not seeking Him but later became a vessel for the Son of God to be revealed in him.

> 5But when God, who set me apart from my mother’s womb and called me by His grace, was pleased 16to reveal His Son in me so that I might preach Him among the Gentiles.  Galatians:1:15

So to answer the OP's question.  Saul is needed for the backdrop for God's grace to be seen by all.

It all started when the witnesses laid their garments at the feet of a young man named Saul.

> This man is My chosen instrument to carry My name before the Gentiles and their kings, and before the people of Israel.  Acts 9:15